# Cantor Bendixson Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have posted this earlier but my proof was a bit incomplete so this is my new proof. I want to know whether it is correct or not, plz help.
$$$$Prove that every uncountable closed set $F$ can be written as $F=A \cup B$ where $A$ is a perfect set and the set $B$ is countable.

$$$$All the sets are the subsets of $R^n$.
$$$$Perfect Set : A Closed set in which all the points are accumulation points.

Condensation Point : A point $x$ in $R^n$ is said to be a condensation Point of $S$ in $R^n$ if every open n-ball $B(x)$ has the property that $B(x) \cap S$ is uncountable.

Let $P$ be the set of all condensation points of $S$ then if $x$ is any point in the set $P^c$ (where $P^c$ is the complement of the set $P$) then there exists an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x) \cap F$ is countable.

Now in this open n-ball if we chose any point $c$ then there exists an open n-ball $B(c)$ such that $B(c)$ lies in $B(x)$ and hence $B(c) \cap F$ is countable and hence $c$ also lies in $P^c$. So for every $x$ in $P^c$ there exists an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x)$ lies in $P^c$.

Hence $P^c$ is an open set and hence $P$ is a closed set. Now as $F$ is a closed set, so $F \cap P$ is also a closed set. Now suppose there exists a point in $F \cap P$ such that there exists an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x)$ contains no point of the set $F \cap P$ except $x$, but as $x$ is a condensation Point so this open n-ball $B(x)$ has the property that $B(x) \cap F$ is uncountable and as $F=(F \cap P) \cup (F-P)$ and as $F-P$ is countable (which I have proved below) so this open n-ball $B(x)$ must contain only  countable points, a contradiction and hence every point in  $F \cap P$ is an accumulation point and hence the set $F \cap P$ is a perfect set, so chose $A=F \cap P$.

Now consider the set $F-P$.

If there is a set $S$ such that for every $x$ in $S$ there is an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x) \cap S$ is countable then the set $S$ is countable. To prove this for every $x$ in $S$ chose this open n-ball with the given above property.

Then this collection of open sets is an  open covering of $S$ and hence by Lindelof's Covering Theorem a countable collection of such sets cover $S$ and each such open set contains only countable number of elements of $S$ and so the set $S$ is countable.

Now in the set $F-P$ for every $x$ there exists an open n-ball $B(x)$ such that $B(x) \cap F$ is countable and hence $B(x) \cap F-P$ is countable and hence by the above property the set $F-P$ is countable. So we chose $B=F-P$. Now as $F=(F \cap P) \cup (F-P)$, so we have $F=A \cup B$ where $A$ is a perfect set and $B$ is countable.

Comment: You need to add to the statement of the theorem that it is for subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ (More generally, the theorem is true when the ambient space is second countable. In fact, I believe that it is always false for non-second countable spaces, though i haven't fully investigated it.)

Comment: "Let us suppose that $P$"... should just be "Let $P$". There is no reason to "suppose" the definition of $P$. Also, the following $S$ should be $F$ as there is no set $S$ defined at this point.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now plz tell me whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Patience, my young Padawan. I'm still reviewing it, and just pointed out a couple minor corrections in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic appears to be complete. I do suggest that you rewrite the proof to be in order, instead of having its completion in the middle followed by a necessary lemma after. Also, try to cut down on repetition of the same phrases and belaboring of trivially obvious points (though, if you are unsure of whether something truly is obvious, best to leave it in).

As Brian M. Scott has already pointed out in your previous post, it is easier to prove from the second countability of $\Bbb R^n$, or more generally for any second countable space.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: More generally it's true for hereditarily Lindelöf spaces, which are not necessarily separable, let alone second countable.